# How to test what image is being displayed using rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Depending on what page is being viewed I want to use a different image for my logo; the logo on the homepage is bigger. I like using request specs to test behaviour, so I would like to do something like this:

```
describe 'Visit "advertentie/1"' do
    it 'contains add details' do
        add = create(:add_with_photos)
        visit add_path add
        page.should have_selector( 'img[alt="logo-small"]' ) # CHECK IMAGE ALT
        page.should have_content( add.name )
    end
end
```

and the test runs agains some haml generated html:

```
<div class='logo-wrapper'>
  <h1>
    <a href="/"><img alt="Logo-big" src="/assets/logo-small.png" />
    <br>
    <span>UpMarket</span>
    </a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

however this selector doesn't work. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: What does the relevant HTML look like?

Comment: Well for a 100% TDD the HTML shouldn't look like anything yet of course, but I'll be a bad way and add it to my question anyway;)

Comment: TDD does mean that you have zero output. There's clearly some HTML that `have_selector` is checking against (or there should be). That's all I was asking for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you try the `have_css` method?

```
have_css("img[src*='w3schools']")
```

(Selects every `<img>` element whose src attribute value contains the substring "w3schools")

Comment: Green specs. Gotta love'em. Thanks, src seemed like a more reliable attribute to test on, since I'd prefer the alts to be a bit more descriptive. Could use this in a lot more situations too, with the `*`, never really used that.

Comment: This works for me but what does the `*` do? All I can find is it being used as "splat" but this seems different. Thanks.

Comment: The `*=` attribute selector means 'the attribute contains the substring'. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for an overview of possible selectors.